# SQL Find the first non null value with arbitrary order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Given the following table:

```
ID | Value
----------
 1 | NULL
 2 |  B
 3 |  C
 4 | NULL
```

I want to get the first non-null value from the Value column according to different ordering, e.g.:

```
SELECT FIRST_NON_NULL(Value ORDER BY ID) FROM MY_TABLE
```

This will return B

```
SELECT FIRST_NON_NULL(Value ORDER BY ID DESC) FROM MY_TABLE
```

This will return C

P.S. Doesn't have to be a value function, just the SELECT statement that is needed. Thank you.

---

Edited: Want to see if there can be a scalable version.

```
ID | Value1 | Value2
--------------------
 1 |  NULL  |   AA
 2 |   B    |  NULL
 3 |   C    |   CC
 4 |  NULL  |  NULL

SELECT FIRST_NON_NULL(Value1, Value2 ORDER BY ID) FROM MY_TABLE
```

This will return B, AA

```
SELECT FIRST_NON_NULL(Value1, Value2 ORDER BY ID DESC) FROM MY_TABLE
```

This will return C, CC

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do :

```
SELECT TOP 1 Value
FROM mytable
WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID
```

To get the *last* not null value switch the ordering:

```
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

To expand the same logic to a greater number of columns you can use the following query:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Value1 FROM mytable 
        WHERE Value1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID) AS min_Value1,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Value2 FROM mytable 
        WHERE Value2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID) AS min_Value2
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/GTI39684)

Comment: Sorry, how do you make it scalable? See updated question.

Answer (score 8):

Original answer is definitely the best for the provided example.

For those out there who need to do this within particular **partitions** and at a **large volume**, this becomes problematic and intensive, as it can translate into a huge number of individual table hits on the back end.

I have a solution using window functions that solves the problem for large data / partitions.

Expanding the original example data as follows - let's have two sets in the data, based on GroupID (1 and 2):

```
GroupID | ID | Value1 | Value2
--------------------------
1       |  1 |  NULL  |   AA
1       |  2 |   B    |  NULL
1       |  3 |   C    |   CC
1       |  4 |  NULL  |  NULL
2       |  5 |   E    |   EE
2       |  6 |   F    |  NULL
2       |  7 |  NULL  |   GG
2       |  8 |  NULL  |  NULL
```

And I want to provide these first/last non-null values *for each GroupID value*, like this:

```
GroupID | FirstValue1 | FirstValue2 | LastValue1 | LastValue2
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       | B           | AA          | C          | CC
2       | E           | EE          | F          | GG
```

If I apply the top 1 logic to scale, and I have lots of rows, it's reaching back to perform tons of individual table queries.  However, if I use window functions, I can have it evaluate data it has in memory to more efficiently get the data, esp when partitions are needed and lots of data.

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT
  GroupID,
  FirstValue1,
  FirstValue2,
  LastValue1,
  LastValue2
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    GroupID,
    ID, Value1, Value2,
    -- Sets a rank so we can reduce to 1 row per GroupID in outer query
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY GroupID
      ORDER BY ID
    ) IDRank,
    FIRST_VALUE(Value1) OVER (
      PARTITION BY GroupID
      ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN Value1 IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, -- Prioritize non-null Value1
        ID                                          -- And ascending ID
    ) FirstValue1,
    FIRST_VALUE(Value2) OVER (
      PARTITION BY GroupID
      ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN Value2 IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, -- Prioritize non-null Value2
        ID                                          -- And ascending ID
    ) FirstValue2,
    FIRST_VALUE(Value1) OVER (
      PARTITION BY GroupID
      ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN Value1 IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, -- Prioritize non-null Value1
        ID DESC                                     -- And descending ID
    ) LastValue1,
    FIRST_VALUE(Value2) OVER (
      PARTITION BY GroupID
      ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN Value2 IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, -- Prioritize non-null Value2
        ID DESC                                     -- And descending ID
    ) LastValue2
  FROM MY_TABLE
  ) BestValues
WHERE IDRank = 1  --Ensures we get only one row per GroupID
ORDER BY GroupID
```

Explained - FIRST_VALUE evaluates within each distinct GroupID (since we set PARTITION BY GroupID).  Within that window, it evaluates, of the rows for that GroupID, cases with non-null values, and then ordering by ID (ascending or descending).
As it is a window function, this puts the value on the level of the records in their original granularity, so we also add a DENSE_RANK to rank and give us the ability to, in the outer query, get down to one row per GroupID.

---

p.s., if you would like to run it yourself, include the following above the query to generate the needed sample data into "MY_TABLE" in a CTE.

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS (
  SELECT 0 as GroupID, 0 AS ID, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) as Value1, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) as Value2 WHERE 0=1 UNION ALL --Dummy row to set types

  SELECT 1 AS GroupID, 1 AS ID, NULL AS Value1, 'AA' AS Value2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS GroupID, 2 AS ID, 'B'  AS Value1, NULL AS Value2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS GroupID, 3 AS ID, 'C'  AS Value1, 'CC' AS Value2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS GroupID, 4 AS ID, NULL AS Value1, NULL AS Value2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS GroupID, 5 AS ID, 'E'  AS Value1, 'EE' AS Value2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS GroupID, 6 AS ID, 'F'  AS Value1, NULL AS Value2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS GroupID, 7 AS ID, NULL AS Value1, NULL AS Value2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS GroupID, 8 AS ID, NULL AS Value1, 'GG' AS Value2
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Solved my lookup problem and addressed the performance issues. Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values

```
SELECT distinct TOP 1 Value
FROM mytable
WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID desc
```

Comment: How could 1 value not be distinct?